# Java abstract class for giving unique ID not working - all of objects have same ID

Tags: java

I have problem with my Java program. Class *Wolumin* is responsible for giving unique ID for the objects in *Object* tab, but it always gives same number to every object. I tried giving variety of acces privilages to it, but nothing seems to be working. In this case each tab object have ID=4, but i want it to be in order :1,2,3,4...

```
public class First {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Object[] tab = new Object[4];
        tab[0]=new Ksiazka("Malysz","Homies");
        tab[1]=new Ksiazka("Pudzian","Malta");
        tab[2]=new Czasopismo("Bravo","420");
        tab[3]=new Czasopismo("Grzyby","2137");
        System.out.println(tab[0].toString());
        System.out.println(tab[1].toString());
        System.out.println(tab[2].toString());
        System.out.println(tab[3].toString());
    }
}
abstract class Wolumin{
    static int id;
    Wolumin(){id++;};
}
class Ksiazka extends Wolumin{
    String autor,tytul;
    Ksiazka(String x, String y){
        this.autor=x;this.tytul=y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (Ksiazka.id+","+autor+","+tytul);
    }
}
class Czasopismo extends Wolumin{
    String tytul,numerWydania;
    Czasopismo(String x, String y){
        tytul=x;
        numerWydania=y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (Czasopismo.id+","+tytul+","+numerWydania);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `id` is static, which means that the ID will be shared across all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` is marked `static`, so all instances of `Wolumin` will have the same value of that variable. You need to have an additional instance variable that is unique to each instance. For example:

```
abstract class Wolumin{
    static int id;
    private final int myId;
    Wolumin(){
        myId = id++;
    };

    int getMyId() {
        return myId;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class Ksiazka extends Wolumin{
    String autor,tytul;
    Ksiazka(String x, String y){
        this.autor=x;this.tytul=y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (getMyId()+","+autor+","+tytul); // use myId instead
    }
}

class Czasopismo extends Wolumin{
    String tytul,numerWydania;
    Czasopismo(String x, String y){
        tytul=x;
        numerWydania=y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (getMyId()+","+tytul+","+numerWydania); // use myId instead
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , wasn't quite sure about this static but now i get it somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

**How to fix the issue?**

Re-arrange the System.out.println statements to print immediately after an object is created.

**Working code:**

```
tab[0]=new Ksiazka("Malysz","Homies");
System.out.println(tab[0].toString());

tab[1]=new Ksiazka("Pudzian","Malta");
System.out.println(tab[1].toString());

tab[2]=new Czasopismo("Bravo","420");
System.out.println(tab[2].toString());

tab[3]=new Czasopismo("Grzyby","2137");
System.out.println(tab[3].toString());
```

**Output of the working code:**

```
$ java First

1,Malysz,Homies
2,Pudzian,Malta
3,Bravo,420
4,Grzyby,2137
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` if you need a threadsafe solution beyond QBrute's approach.
This class has the methods incrementAndGet() and getAndIncrement(), which both do what you need.